# Way to go about implementing an 'Add Friends' feature on a site?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, friend

I've tried looking through tons of posts on here but haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for but, currently working on a project for my bootcamp that is  a site that is essentially a social anime site, where you have your own dedicated User Profile but you can add friends.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to implement this into the application despite seeing several different kinds of social media projects. The project is built on Spring Boot and uses Java.

We have a User Profile class which has the variables: UUID userID, String displayName, Date birthday, String aboutMe. But would we have to create a variable like 'List friendsList', within each User profile? Then create methods within that User class that call for adding/removing friends (like somehow send a request to a User and then when that person accepts, they're added to the 'List friendsList'?

Or would creating a whole Friends class, controller, service ect be the route to go? And how would one go about that in a general sense.

Comment: Are you looking for a high level design of this feature, or you want to understand how the low level design will work in spring boot?

Comment: Just a low level design and how it can integrate within Spring Boot! Its hard for me to grasp how it all really works. In some instances, when you add friends, they're able to view more of your profile than someone that isn't a friend.

Comment: Do u already have a database setup, does it already contains a User table?

Comment: I do! Have a User Record, User Controller for the API, User Service class, and a User table that is hosted in AWS using DynamoDB.

Comment: If you want me to post code, I'd be happy too! Just didn't want to flood the post is all. :)

Answer (score 0):

you correctly understood that for a UserA, you have to store a List of Friends. The relationship is 1 to here N.

The easiest solution is to created another table "FriendsMapping", with 2 columns: owner & friend and both have a foreign key to the User table.

If you want that UserA has two friends UserB and UserC, you will have the Friends table with 2 entries:

```
owner: UserA, friend: UserB
owner: UserA, friend: UserC
```

To fetch all friends of a user, you execute:

```
SELECT * FROM friends where owner = UserA
```

EDIT: if you use Hibernate, you can have projection lists which automatically fetch the friends when requesting the list, see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)